# LuaInterface error " '=' expected near '<eof>' "

Tags: c#, lua, luainterface

I'm trying to learn lua and how lua can be used with C#.
So I've created a lua script in which I declared a string variable called "x":

```
local x = "String variable"
```

Then I've tried to load the string from the c# program like this:

```
LuaFunction vsa =  lua.LoadString("x", "root.lua");
```

When I try to compile I receive this error:

> `[string "root.lua"]:1: '=' expected near '<eof>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are trying to make is basically this:

```
function(...)
    x
end
```

This function isn't valid; You're reading `x` but not doing anything with it, and since Lua expressions can't exist as statements, you get a parse error.

What you meant is probably `lua.LoadString("return x", "root.lua")`. However, this still won't work, because `x` is local to the file which you defined it in; outside functions can't access it. Either `x` needs to be global or (more preferably) you define a getter function inside the file that you define `x` in.

Comment: Could you show me an example of how to declare a global-readable value in lua? Can it be declared without a function?

Comment: Just don't declare it `local`. i.e. `x = "String variable"`